# External CSS file is not loading in the browser

Tags: css, configuration, mime-types, mime

So first of all, I want to preface by saying I am very new to programming so forgive me if I don't follow as quickly.

Now, I am having a problem that is really bothering me for the last few days and I have searched everywhere for a solution.

I am using a WAMP server configuration. Everything has been working fine until I started working with CSS. I have an external CSS file.

When I view my HTML page in Dreamweaver, I see that it is properly connecting to that CSS file. I can see the styles being applied in the Design view. However, when I view the page in the browser, Firefox says (in Error Console) that the .css file cannot be loaded because its MIME type is text/html and not text/css.

So I figured this was a server configuration problem. What I did was the following:
I went into the .HTACCESS file and added the following line:
AddType text/css .css

After restarting my server, this still did not solve the problem. For some reason, the browser keeps reading my css file as an html file. Any idea what could possibly going wrong here?

Here's the head of the file I'm trying to load in the browser (it's actually a Smarty template):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../htdocs/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
```

Also, please note that I am coding using a Zend framework. 
Here is my .HTACCESS file:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

AddType text/css .css

So I took the advice of DA and clicked on View Page Source when viewing the page in browser and clicked on the link to my CSS file. This is what it shows me:

When I click on link, I see this:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0'  cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in C:\shaancode\www\phpweb20\htdocs\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line <i>248</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception: Invalid controller specified (error) in C:\shaancode\www\phpweb20\htdocs\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line <i>248</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>382488</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\shaancode\www\phpweb20\htdocs\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0892</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>4748936</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(  )</td><td title='C:\shaancode\www\phpweb20\htdocs\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>42</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: what's the file name of your css file and when you view the browser what does you link stylesheet tag say?

Comment: Hey Shaan, we need to see the HTML of the head to figure out what is going on. Once you post that content, we'll have more of an idea of whats going on.

Comment: what does the contents of your CSS file look like?

Comment: Open your page from your server in Firefox. Go to VIEW SOURCE. In the source file, click on the URL to your CSS file. What loads? My guess is that your CSS file link isn't linking to a file, so your server is serving it as a custom error page. That page would be HTML, hence the error.

Comment: I pasted above what I see when I click on that link. i see some kind of error here but not sure I understand what's going on? OH, it looks like this is the styling for when Zend displays an error. Hm. WHy would it be showing that?

Comment: This is because of the path issue I explained earlier. You're using a relative path in your CSS when you should be using absolute path. Using the headlink helper will solve this for you

Comment: @Shaan: Yep, your path is wrong. It's not even finding the CSS file. You're getting an application error, which is being served as HTML, hence the error message you were getting previously. I don't know ZEND, but, typically, these frameworks have very particular preferences as to how you are supposed to reference all your files.

Answer (score 1):

```
href="../htdocs/css/styles.css"
```

The htdocs directory is usually the webroot. So, while this is a perfectly good path on your local file system, once you access it through a webserver the `../` is ignored because you are in the top of the local part already. Then there is no `htdocs` so the rest of the path should 404.

For some reason, Zend is sending out its "Invalid controller specified (error)" (meaning "I can't find what I've been asked for" with a 200 OK status code, so the browser is saying "This is an HTML document" instead of "Nothing was found there".

Remove the `../htdocs/` part from the URL.

Comment: If I remove the htdocs/ part from the URL, it can't find the css file anymore in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Shaan you really should NOT depend on viewing CSS rendered in Dreamweaver. It's never been good, always has bugs. Use DW as a nice text editor, but use your web browser to see how the site actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using CSS probably by using `<link rel=stylesheet href="cssName.html">`
This may be similar to the [Mozilla Bug](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/project_owners/2008-January/010830.html). Please share you code so that we can provide better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here can be two fold. Either the CSS file is missing and your system is serving up a 404 page (if you've configured it) so the browser is complaining that it's not a CSS file.

Or the problem could be that you have a server configuration issue. If it's a new installation of WAMP, this is pretty unlikely.

Have you tried accessing the file directly?

- View the source in Firefox (or any  browser)
- click on the CSS link you've made. If you can't click on it you may have to copy paste it in a new window.
- Does it take you to the CSS file or some other file?

If it takes you to another file that means you haven't linked it properly. You may be better off using an absolute path (from your webroot) rather than a relative path.

**EDIT** : Using stylesheets in Zend Framework

Assuming your CSS files are in ZF/public/css, you would include them in your layout or view like this

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/styleForThisPage.css'); // in your view
```

Designate an area for it to be printed out (in your layout)

```
echo $this->headLink()
```

**However, if it's a sitewide css file** and you want to include your CSS only in the layout, then simply echoing it out will suffice

```
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/global.css');
```

Comment: The file is linked properly. I've loaded it in Firefox. When it loads, I see the CSS document in plain text. If I select View Page Info from my browser, it says type: text/css.

Comment: Paste your .htaccess file into your question. also, are you using any PHP frameworks or virtual hosts?

Comment: Sure, I will update the question. Also I am using Zend framework. I simply set up localhost as my virtual host.

Comment: Then the problem might be a path issue. you should use the urlhelper or the headlink helper to include your CSS

Comment: Oh I see. Can you please elaborate how to use urlhelper or headlink helper?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! A lot of you were right, it ultimately had to do with the href path. So, I was able to fix the error, but it seems the solution was simple and the problem silly!

In Dreamweaver, I did not define the Site Root folder!! This was causing a problem because I was using a relative path, but it wasn't finding it correctly ultimately because the Site Root wasn't defined!

So I set the Site Root in Dreamweaver to my Root directory (where .HTACCESS is located) and changed the path to simply "/css/styles.css".

And now it works!

Sorry to trouble everyone and thank you all for your help!

Comment: Up vote the answers that helped you, please. Glad you got it working.